# How to query multiple data from aws dynamo db?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

im using aws dynamo db to fetch all datas from a userkyc table where kyc_status should be "A" and "D". Below code i can only use either "A" or "D". How do i fetch all data for both conditions. Help will be appreciated!

```
  var params = {
            TableName: "user_kyc",
            ProjectionExpression: "email, uid, kyc_status",
            KeyConditionExpression: "#kyc_status = :kyc_status",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#kyc_status": "kyc_status",
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":kyc_status": "A"
               

            },
            FilterExpression: "#kyc_status = :kyc_status"
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your params to something like:

```
var params = {
   TableName: "user_kyc",
   ProjectionExpression: "email, uid, kyc_status",
   KeyConditionExpression: "#kyc_status = :kyc_status1 or #kyc_status = :kyc_status2",
   ExpressionAttributeNames: {
     "#kyc_status": "kyc_status",
   },
   ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":kyc_status1": "A",
     ":kyc_status2": "D"
   }
};
```

Here I added another variable, now there is :kyc_status1 and :kyc_status2, and used this now variable in KeyConditionExpression to do a **or** expression.